# HTML and CSS in order to fix footer content of a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone teach me how to create a footer div which is always stay at the bottom of the website regardless of how much information is present in the middle and the most important thing here is that I'm not fixed any height property for the middle content(Please notice that is "website" not "window" because I don't want to fixed the footer that force the user always see the footer whenever they scroll up or scroll down in my website) A specific example is like Facebook that footer always at the end of the page no matter how many times you click older post button. Is there anyway possible in HTML and CSS or even javascript to do that. Please help me and thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: This is very basic HTML. Google would present you with a solution in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used stickyfooter in the past. You can learn it here http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1):

You put the footer content after the other content. That's all.

(Unless you need to deal with earlier content that is positioned out of normal flow, is floating, etc).

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a master page with the footer div in it. Please take a look at this MSDN article for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want the footer to be pushed down to the bottom of the window if the content isn't high enough to fill the window, use the technique offered in [this article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page).

To summarize the article:

1. Create a wrapper around the page elements:

   > ```
   > <div id="container">
   >   <div id="header"></div>
   >   <div id="body"></div>
   >   <div id="footer"></div>
   > </div>
   > ```
2. Using CSS, give the body `100%` height and give the container `position`:

   > ```
   > html, body {
   >   margin:  0;
   >   padding: 0;
   >   height:  100%;
   > }
   > #container {
   >   min-height: 100%;
   >   position:   relative;
   > }
   > ```
3. Again using CSS, give the content (in this example, `#body`), a `padding-bottom` with the height of the footer and position the footer absolutely at `bottom: 0`:

   > ```
   > #body {
   >   padding-bottom: 60px; /* Height of the footer */
   > }
   > #footer {
   >   position: absolute;
   >   bottom:   0;
   >   width:    100%;
   >   height:   60px; /* Height of the footer */
   > }
   > ```

It's important that the footer has a **fixed height** (i.e. in `px` or `em`).

You can see a demonstration of this technique here: http://jsfiddle.net/PPvG/F7Fph/